# One zip code for several places/towns

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I use GMap places library's autocomplete feature like this :

```
var autoc = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}});
```

I type zipcode and it gives suggestions, all is fine. But in France, one zip code can be used by several towns. It seems GMap proposes only one place for each zip code. Is it a known issue?

Any idea to counter this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not limited to France.  There are places in the US where several (usually small) towns are covered by the same zip code, and there are several (usually large) cities that have multiple zip codes.

Comment: Thx. It's almost good to know: it means I could get some help not only from France but worldwide hehe. Do you know a way to deal with this? Do you know how google map "choose" the town? It doesn't seems to be the biggest one.

Comment: A zip code is something like a Post Office identifier. One post office can deliver to pretty big regions (multiple towns), depending on population density.